# NextJS folders structure

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm migrating ReactJS to NextJS because of the need for SEO, in my project I was organizing my files by the context of example pages.

```
    src
    _ components
    _ _ Footer
    _ _ _ index.js
    _ _ _ Footer.modules.scss
    _ _ Header
    _ _ _ index.js
    _ _ _ Header.module.scss
    _pages
    _ _ Home
    _ _ _ components
    _ _ _ _ Banner
    _ _ _ _ _ index.js
    _ _ _ _ _ Banner.module.scss
    _ _ _ _ More...
    _ _ _ index.js
    _ _ _ Home.module.scss
    _ _ More...
```

But in NextJS the routing is done on the basis of organizing the files into `pages`, and `components` can no longer be together with `pages`.
how do I organize my `components` referring to their `pages`? maintaining this concept of an organization that brings together everything that is part of a context.

I've researched a lot about it but I haven't found anything and in every example, I see all the `components` are together in the same `components` folder in the root of `src`.

I read about [Next Right Now](https://unlyed.github.io/next-right-now/reference/folder-structure) they talk about it, but I don't know if I'm on the right path.

Sorry for the English, "google translator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing like this:

```
    src
    _ modules
    _ _ common
    _ _ about
    _ _ contact-us
    _ _ photos
    _ _ _ PhotosPage.js
    _ _ _ PhotosPage.messages.js
    _ _ _ PhotosPage.module.scss
    _ pages
    _ _ about.js // refers to '../modules/about/AboutPage.js
    _ _ contact-us.js
    _ _ photos.js // refers to '../modules/photos/PhotosPage.js
```

Comment: Hi @MyTitle, I see this organization corresponds to [Next Right Now](https://unlyed.github.io/next-right-now/reference/folder-structure) and keeps the organization I was following, thanks!